# How to use "if any"? How would you finish this sentence?

Tags: if

Is this sentence correct? Is there a better way to say this?

> It is debated which method is better if any.

Comment: It needs a comma after better. Otherwise, it's ok although I'd prefer to move the **if any** back to the word **method**, which it modifies. **It is debated which method, if any, is better.

Comment: Do you mean: It is not clear which method is better? **If so**, we say debatable and not debated. Too bad the downvoters on my answer do not know the rules for using simple present passive.

Answer (score 1):

> It is debated which method is better, if any.

In terms of grammar this is correct. However "if any" doesn't work well with a comparative and especially a comparative that has no clear metric.

Let's replace "better" with "suitable".

**Example**

*It is debated which methods are suitable, if any.*

This makes sense because some methods may be suitable or none may be suitable. The phrase "if any" indicates the possibility that none of the methods might be suitable.

**Answer**

The form of your sentence is correct but the usage is incorrect. There is no need to say "if any". It is better to say *"It is debated which method is better"*

---

P.S.

By using "better", you have restricted yourself to two methods. If there are many then say

*"It is debated which method is best"*

or

*"It is debated which methods are best"*

Comment: Can you indicate to me when you might use: it is debated rather than it is debatable....I am quite annoyed by my downvote (NOT saying it was you) and don't understand how a fine UK speaker like yourself missed the ted/able thing.

Answer (score -1):

- It is debated by the Parliament [point in time implication for habitual action: **every year].**

As in: The issue is debated by the Parliament every year.

*It* could be: the issue, the problem, etc.

*A simple present, even if passive, is used for a **habitual action**.* A simple present passive is very unlikely....

However, grammatically,this is said like this:

- The better method, if any, is debated [by whomever].

**But I think what is meant is probably:**

**Which method is better, if any, is debatable.** [and **not** debated].

if any comes after what it refers to, whether a noun or clause.

It means: If any method is better is debatable.

You could also say: It is debatable which method, if any, is better.